# How to display a still image of a place seeked by Unity's EasyMovieTexture

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using EasyMovieTexture on Unity to play videos.And I'm seeking a video using the slider UI.
When seeking and calling Play (), I can play from the targeted position.

Well, when I seek, I want to display a still image of the target position without playing it.
However, I can not find the corresponding method in the MediaPlayerCtrl class of EasyMovieTexture.
Please let me know if you know how to display the still image in the seek position with EasyMovieTexture.

Thanks.

Comment: I think I was trying the same couple of years ago and did not get it. I think I ended up with playing for a single frame and stop, so it loads the image and pause. Somehow running a coroutine Play(); yield return null; Pause(); but can't recall if it actually did the trick.

Comment: Unity's EasyMovieTexture isn't actually that good. There's some video players on the asset store that are *much*  better and all cost like $5 or $10. Some even have a free demo version.